# undefined is not an object RCTCameraRollManager of React-Native CameraRoll

Tags: xcode, react-native, react-native-camera

I need to save captured photo to cameraRoll in my react-native app.
I uses react-native-camera and I try to save photo to roll with CameraRoll of React-Native.

```
CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(uri, 'photo');
```

I keep getting this error of  `undefined is not an object evaluating RCTCameraRollManager.saveToCameraRoll`

Within most of the questions the suggestion was adding `RCTCameraRoll.xcodeproj` to libraries and linking `libRCTCameraRoll.a` in buil phase linking libraries. I done both of them, but I still get the same error.

Here is screenshot of my project structure and build phases.

https://www.imageupload.co.uk/image/EI9l

Is there someone could manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

executing `npm start --reset-cache` solved my problem.

Have a nice day.